# Subtracting value from Nth row based on condition

Tags: r, data.table, lag

I am trying to see if I can perform a lag in data.table based on a condition in one of my columns

```
               Variable          Range     Avg.Concentration
1          m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1) blank          0.000000
2          m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1)  dms1          0.000000
3          m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1)  dms2          0.000000
4          m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1)  dms3          0.000000
5          m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1)  dms4          0.000000
6          m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1) blank          0.103741
7          m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1)  dms1          0.107979
8          m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1)  dms2          0.108123
9          m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1)  dms3          0.104491
10         m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1)  dms4          0.104051
11         m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2) blank          1.391382
12         m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2)  dms1          1.025274
13         m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2)  dms2          1.007375
14         m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2)  dms3          1.068320
15         m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2)  dms4          1.154035
```

What I need to do is for every group of variable (m21, m33, m39 etc.) is I need to create a new column called 'Calculated Concentration' where the values in the column are equal to the Average Concentration for the blank subtracted from the Average Concentration of dms1, dms2 dms3 etc.

For example for rows 7-10 where the Variable is m33 I would need in this new calculated concentration column:
7: 0.107979 - 0.103741 (value of dms1-blank for m33)
8: 0.108123 - 0.103741 (value of dms2-blank for m33)
9: 0.104491 - 0.103741 (value of dms3 - blank for m33)
10: 0.104051 - 0.103741 (value of dms4 -blank for m33)

For every unique variable, the value for the blank changes which is why I can't set the blank to a constant value.

When I only had two options for Range (dms and blank) I was able to just use lag to subtract the Avg, Concentration from the row above it which looked like this:

```
               Variable          Range     Avg.Concentration
1          m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1)  blank         0.000000
2          m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1)  dms           0.000000
3          m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1)  blank         0.103741
4          m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1)  dms           0.107979
5         m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2)   blank         1.391382
6         m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2)   dms           1.025274
```

`#calculate concentration (average - blank)`
`df[, Cal.Concentration := Avg.Concentration - shift(Avg.Concentration, fill = first(Avg.Concentration))]`

Ideally what I would like is some kind of function to say if Range == "dms1" subtract the value for Avg.Concentration from the row above, if Range == 'dms2' subtract the value for Avg. Concentration from two rows above, if Range == 'dms3' subtract the value for Avg. Concentration for three rows above and if Range == 'dms4' subtract the Value for Avg. Concentration for 4 rows above.

I doesn't have to be using data.table, I am open to suggestions. I have found a work-around for the time being but it is really time consuming as it involves making a new column called 'blank' to store the value for the blank for every unique variable and then I just subtract the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```r
quux[, Cal.Concentration := Avg.Concentration - Avg.Concentration[Range == "blank"],
     by = .(Variable)]
quux
#                  Variable  Range Avg.Concentration Cal.Concentration
#                    <char> <char>             <num>             <num>
#  1: m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1)  blank          0.000000          0.000000
#  2: m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1)   dms1          0.000000          0.000000
#  3: m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1)   dms2          0.000000          0.000000
#  4: m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1)   dms3          0.000000          0.000000
#  5: m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1)   dms4          0.000000          0.000000
#  6: m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1)  blank          0.103741          0.000000
#  7: m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1)   dms1          0.107979          0.004238
#  8: m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1)   dms2          0.108123          0.004382
#  9: m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1)   dms3          0.104491          0.000750
# 10: m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1)   dms4          0.104051          0.000310
# 11: m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2)  blank          1.391382          0.000000
# 12: m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2)   dms1          1.025274         -0.366108
# 13: m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2)   dms2          1.007375         -0.384007
# 14: m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2)   dms3          1.068320         -0.323062
# 15: m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2)   dms4          1.154035         -0.237347
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- setDT(structure(list(Variable = c("m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1)", "m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1)", "m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1)", "m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1)", "m21.021 (H[1]3O[16]1)", "m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1)", "m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1)", "m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1)", "m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1)", "m33.993 (O[16]2H[1]1)", "m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2)", "m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2)", "m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2)", "m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2)", "m39.032 (H[1]5O[16]2)"), Range = c("blank", "dms1", "dms2", "dms3", "dms4", "blank", "dms1", "dms2", "dms3", "dms4", "blank",  "dms1", "dms2", "dms3", "dms4"), Avg.Concentration = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.103741, 0.107979, 0.108123, 0.104491, 0.104051, 1.391382, 1.025274, 1.007375, 1.06832, 1.154035), Cal.Concentration = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00423800000000001, 0.004382, 0.000750000000000001, 0.000310000000000005, 0, -0.366108, -0.384007, -0.323062, -0.237347)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```